# Is there a way to import a PCB layout from one "sheet" into a multisheet in KiCad?

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I am making a multisheet schematic and I'm appending schematics from other projects into the multisheet. They take their netlist along with them which is great but,

**is there a way to take their PCB layout with them from their respective projects so I don't have to layout the appended schematics again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda. `File > Append Board...` to get something like this:-

[image: pcb]

and in 3D viewer you can clearly see 2 PCBs:-

[image: 3d-view]

The trick is that both the schematic editor and PCB editor have to be opened 'stand alone'. You can't use the top level command utility and work within a project. It all has to be stand alone. `File > Append Board...` isn't on offer either if it's a project.

I didn't re-annotate the schematics (as that would mess up my stuff) but seems to work. You will see that components now have the same reference ID (C1 & D1  for example). It's not ideal and you'll have address this manually. But there's the picture evidence above.

I guess that you then relocate existing laid out areas from PCB and scrap the other PCB.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really well handled by kicad… it works with the one project = one board philosophy. Also in the new versions the "root sheet" is special, you can't do the trick of using the subsheets to make different pcbs.

If you want to make more than one board from one schematic drawing the only good way I see is to draw all the boards in one layout and then split them at the gerber postprocess stage.